# Half precision in batch normalization

Tags: precision, batch-normalization

Why is it a common practice to have single precision for batch normalization Even when the rest of the network is of half precision?

Comment: to reduce the effect of accumulated floating point errors on the moving statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to reduce the effect of accumulated floating point errors on the moving statistics – shimao